# max-margin linear separator using libsvm

Tags: machine-learning, classification, svm, libsvm

I have a set of N data points X with +/- labels for which I'd like to calculate the max-margin linear separator (aka classifier, hyperplane) or fail if no such linear separator exist.

I do not want to avoid overfitting in the context of this question, as I do so elsewhere. So no slack variables ; no cross-validation ; no limits on the number of support vectors ; just find max-margin separator or fail.

How to I use libsvm to do so? I believe you can't give c=0 in C-SVM and you can't give nu=1 in nu-svm.

Related question (which I think didn't provide an answer):
[Which of the parameters in LibSVM is the slack variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9375502/which-of-the-parameters-in-libsvm-is-the-slack-variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of C-SVM, you should use a linear kernel and a very large C value (or nu = 0.999... for nu-SVM). If you still have slacks with this setting, probably your data is not linearly separable.

Quick explanation: the C-SVM optimization function tries to find the hyperplane having maximum margin and lowest misclassification costs at the same time. The misclassification costs in the C-SVM formulation is defined by: distance from the misclassified point to its correct side of the hyperplane, multiplied by C. If you increase the C value (or nu value for nu-SVM), every misclassified point will be too costly and an hyperplane that separates the data perfectly will be preferable for the optimization function.

Comment: nu=1 does not work in nu-SVM, but c=1e10 does work for me in C-SVM, so I'll accept this answer :)

Comment: You are right. Theoretically, nu = 1 would be ideal. But LibSVM does not accept it. I edited the answer to nu = 0.999.